# How to deobfuscate jar file

Tags: java, jar, deobfuscation

Is there is any open source tool for deobfuscation? Not able to read the decompiled files its showing class/method as A/B/C etc

Comment: There wouldn't be much point in obfuscating a file if you could deobfuscate it, would there? If your plans are legitimate, contact the author and ask for an unobfuscated version.

Comment: BTW: I disagree with those who try to close this question. I think this is a valid SO question, even though it's probably not answerable.

Comment: If the obfuscated classes still can be decompiled into valid java code, the obfuscation wasn't very aggressive.

Answer (score 6):

The only open-source tool for deobfuscating in a *meaningful* way is your head.

Reverse engineering is hard, and requires patience, fortitude, caffeine, ESP, and Star Trek.

Comment: I'm wondering whether to up- or downvote this answer :-)

Comment: Completely agree. Been down this road before and you have to trace through it line by line manually. A lot of times lines look like they make no sense or do nothing.

Answer (score 5):

As far I know, there is no such tool. I can't envisage it being possible, as there is no way for a deobfuscation tool to know what meaningful names to give to methods and classes.

And that is why people obfuscate.

Comment: +1 People wouldn't pay money for obfuscation tools if they could be de-obfuscated for free.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that once a jar file is obsfucated the original names are destroyed and usually replaced with shortened ones.  You could try adding the obsfucated file to a project and using  refactor tools to replace with more meaningful names, as you refactor the code you give the classes more meaningful names as their purpose becomes clearer